# SQL Таблица и питон

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

В процессе написание скрипта на появилась необходимость использования БД. Оплатил хостинг и получил доступ к phpMyAdmin. В этой панеле создал и заполнил таблицу. В ходе работы со скриптом столкнулся со следующей проблемой: успешно подключаюсь к таблице и получаю значения, но изменить их не могу, код выполняется но значение не меняется. При выполнении команды внутри phpMyAdmin работает как нужно.

Код, который не работает:

```
try:
    connection = pymysql.Connect(
        host=host,
        user=user,
        password=password,
        database=db_name,
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
 
    )
    print('Подключился')
except Exception as ex:
    print('Не прошло')
    print(ex)
 
 
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    update_query = "UPDATE config SET workState = '596' WHERE id = '1';"
    cursor.execute(update_query)
    
 
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    select_all_rows = "SELECT * FROM config"
    cursor.execute(select_all_rows)
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    print(row)
```

Подскажите что делаю не так, и как исправить ситуацию

Comment: Покажите скрипт. Что конкретно значит "изменить не могу"? Напишите, как запускаете скрипт. Какой результат запуска? Как проверяете данные после? Без этого - не поможем.

Comment: изменить не могу значит, что я через phpMyAdmin вижу значение в таблице, но используя питон уже у себя на ПК после успешного коннекта и выполнения запроса это значение не изменяется. Как я понял проблема в самом хостинге который не позволяет редактировать бд из вне. Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно реализовать внешнюю БД, чтобы к ней можно было подключатся и изменять значения из нескольких независимых ПК

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html) pymysql не делает фиксацию изменений в БД (по английски commit), нужно делать это явно:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    update_query = "UPDATE config SET workState = '1' WHERE id = '1';"
    cursor.execute(update_query)
connection.commit()
```